# How to test Java SSH client jsch?

Tags: java, ssh

I have assignment to read about java SSH client(jsch).
I read a couple examples,but when I tried some of these,I always getting the same error.
**Connection refused: connect**
Can I tried on my host,just for testing purpose.I am new to this.Just want to no get any errors. 
Here is example that I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = "username";
        String host = "host ip";
        int port = 22;
        String privateKey = ".ssh/id_rsa";

        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
        System.out.println("identity added ");

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        System.out.println("session created.");

         java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
         config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
         session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();
        System.out.println("session connected.....");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("shell channel connected....");

        ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        String fileName = "test.txt";
        c.put(fileName, "./in/");
        c.exit();
        System.out.println("done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Can you connect to the same host using another SFTP or SSH client?

Comment: I haven't tried.I will right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection refused" means that the client sent a TCP connection request to the server, and it received a response from the server refusing request.

The simplest explanation is that there is nothing listening for connections on the address and port that the client tried to connect to. In this case, it would mean that there's no SSH server process running on the remote server, or it's running but it not configured to listen for connections on the correct address and port.

Alternately, "connection refused" could mean that a firewall or some similar network device is blocking the connection requests from the client.