# No connection to self-hosted Docker-Gitlab Instance possible

Tags: git, docker, ssh, gitlab-ce

I have a self-hosted Docker-Gitlab (v.16.8 currently) and it worked for some years. Then, a year ago I disabled it, recently enabled it again and updated it. The Gitlab webpage, the CI jobs, the Container Registry and all that works. What does not work, though, is my ability to interact with the server via Git through SSH, e.g. `git clone ssh://git@INTERNETIP:10022/repo.git`

Extended error log when connecting from my machine to the Docker-Gitlab instance hosted on an Ubuntu LTS (5.15.0-91) server

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/christian/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for myurl.tld
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "myurl.tld" port 10022
debug3: resolve_host: lookup myurl.tld:10022
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to myurl.tld [externalip] port 10022.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address externalip port 10022: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host myurl.tld port 10022: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The setup is the following:

- Gitlab in Docker with default OpenSSH, SSH port inside of container is `22`, outside it is `10022`. Relevant entries of `gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'https://myurl.tld'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022
gitlab_sshd['enable'] = false # also tried with true (which is the new Gitlab-made SSH server)
#gitlab_sshd['listen_address'] = '[::]:22' # also tried 10022 here
```

- The Docker container start command (without the mounted volumes) is

```
docker run \
--detach \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
-p 10022:22 -p 10080:80 -p 10443:443 -p 4567:4567 \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

- The Gitlab Docker container is connected to the default Docker network "bridge" (see below config excerpt). Note that I can connect to Port 443 (actually external port 10443) successfully since I see the Docker-Gitlab HTTPS webpage.

```
"Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        ...
}
"Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
```

- I can also successfully connect to other Docker containers on that bridge network from the outside. The Web containers in Docker are made accessible through Nginx Reverse Proxy, e.g.

```
# nginx.conf
server {
       list INTERNETIP:443 ssl http2;
       server_name myurl.tld;
...
       location ~ ^/.* {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:10443;
                proxy_set_header Host              $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
...
```

- SSH keys and GPG keys were added to Gitlab instance and are still valid.
  To connect to it, so far I always used `git clone ssh://git@INTERNETIP:10022/repo.git` but this fails the same way as just doing an SSH connect to this address (w/o the repo of course). The config file is set up and the SSH agent knows about the certificate.
- In an external firewall the port is opened, and on the server itself there is no IP tables block rule (actually, I even added for testing an iptables entry almost at the top of the chain `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10022 -j ACCEPT`). I double verified for firewall issues by disabling the container and starting a Python-SimpleHTTPServer on that port 10022. I can access the webpage from my device.
- I tried also to set up a second SSHD instance in an interactive connection inside of the Gitlab Docker container on a different port, and I forward the external port 10022 to this interactive SSHD session instead of the default session on port 22. When I try to connect it shows nothing, as if Docker does not forward the request at all. Interestingly, though, the start log shows

```
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does not match private key
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:xxx
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key does not match private key
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxx
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key does not match private key
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:xxx
```

I have tracked the issue a bit:

- when I am connected via SSH to the server hosting the Docker-Gitlab instance and I do a `git clone ssh://git@127.0.0.1:10022/repo.git`, a `ssh -vvT git@172.17.0.3 -p 22` (the internal IP of the docker container), or even a `ssh -vvvT git@127.0.0.1 -p 10022`, I get a successful connection and can issue SSH and GIT commands (also to my custom SSHD session from above).
- However, it does not work anymore while still on server when I try the same commands with the public IP or myurl.tld. Then I get the same errors as I get when doing it from my device.

How can I further test/debug this matter and find out what stops me from connecting to the Git server as I did a year ago?

EDIT:
Here are the current iptables rules, which were auto-generated by docker

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N f2b-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j f2b-ssh
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4567 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-ssh -j RETURN
```

Comment: Do you know what the "Connection refused" error normally means? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49906423/13317

Comment: @Kenster: I also think it has something to do with the iptables settings - yet I do not see what - especially since I did not change them in any way. See the Edit in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more inspection and tests, especially with the firewall, it dawned on me: it is the port mapping. Somewhen back, it seems the default behavior of docker to map ports has changed?!
My above script with `-p 10022:22` maps the external port 10022 to the internal port 22, yet only on the interface 127.0.0.1 when I issue a `docker ps`. This prevents me from accessing the system from the outside via port 10022. Then the question is, why does the webinterface on port 10443 work? Well, for this I had a reverse proxy entry set up, so the HTTP/HTTPS calls are actually coming from 127.0.0.1 due to the Nginx reverse proxy.

Quick Fix:
The solution for me is to force-bind the container to the external interface, or even to all interfaces, e.g. `-p 0.0.0.0:10022:22`

Real Fix (and root cause of problem):
Plesk (server admin tool) added w/o prior notification an entry to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to bind all container by default to `127.0.0.1` to prevent external access ([1](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/17895328139671)), which in the mean time got reverted back. However, every installation that had this update installed (thanks, auto-update...) still has this setting specified. You have to manually remove that entry from `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart the docker daemon.

Comment: That's strange. The docs ([1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#publish), [2](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports)) say the default is `0.0.0.0` and one should prepend `127.0.0.1` manually.

Comment: Then please point to the config issue above. I have posted the command with which I start the docker container. It also worked exactly that way before for me and after a year and updates on Docker, Gitlab and server, it suddenly does not anymore (which is the reason for starting this topic). Should someone else come across this behavior, check the IP's the ports are bound to.

Comment: The default could be configured in [`/etc/docker/daemon.json`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file), key `"ip":`; or command-line parameter `--ip` to `dockerd`. Are you sure yours were not changed from defaults?

Comment: @phd good point! this file has been changed and now includes the entry `"ip": "127.0.0.1"`
I could identify now the root cause: it seems, Plesk (admin tool) had a "feature" to enhance security some time ago, they changed that behavior in the mean time, but did not roll back the change they just did. Updated the answer above